# EF6 Model browser not shows anything

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I have just reinstall window 10 then I installed SQL Server 2017, SSMS 18.1, Visual Studio 2019 (.NET desktop and ASP.NET development). I opened my old  ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) (this project had been created before I reinstall win 10) and opened ADO.NET Entity Data Model but when I open model browser, it only show model browser tab but it don't have anything inside, sometime it's transparent inside.

There are things i've tried:

- New data model, new project
- Reinstall VS
- Reinstall Win 10

If this is VS bug, I'll try to install VS 2017

Comment: Were you previously using EF 6 in your application or EF 4 or 5?  Is the application written in C# or VB.Net?

Comment: EF 6 and it's c# app

Comment: My other WPF project using EF 6 can't see anything in model browser too

Comment: I have this same issue, nothing in the Model Browser tab. If I open the same project in VS2017 I can see the Model Browser. I also used to be able to click on my model diagram, press F4 to get the properties and then choose the entity from the drop down at the top which made finding the item in a big diagram easy, however now the only option I have in there is 'ConceptualEntityModel'. I recently started targeting .NET 4.7.2 but can't remember if this issue started at the same time